# Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint widget is always active

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have a main window (QMainWindow) and a widget with flag Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint that provides auxiliary information and options (let's call it helper). If I work with main window and then click on any other application this window ceases to be active (isActiveWindow() == false). But if I work with the helper first and then I switch to other application/window (not to Main Window) it stays to be active. How can I handle switching from the helper window to other application? Even QApplication::activeWindow() returns true because of this.

.h file:

```
//! Popup structure that contains listw_popup that shows tips
struct PopupWidget {
    PopupWidget(QWidget*);

    QWidget *base;
    QListWidget *listw_popup;
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    ...
private :
    PopupWidget popup_spec;
    ...
}
```

.cpp file:

```
PopupWidget::PopupWidget(QWidget* parent)
{
    base = new QWidget(parent, Qt::SplashScreen | Qt::WindowStaysOnTop);
    listw_popup = new QListWidget(base);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : ... popup_spec(this) ...
{
    ...
}
```

When popup_spec.base.show() is called this widget appears. And if I click on this widget (means the widget becomes active) it stays to be active even if I switch to other application.

Comment: What behavior do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Jay I need helper window disappears when I switched from this application to another.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I'm assuming the helper widget is a parent-less widget right? can you show some minimal code showing your current behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if I follow your requirements correctly,

You want you helper widget(which has `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint`) to be hidden when the application loses focus.

You could try something like this:

In your `MainWindow.cpp` say in the constructor add:

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);
```

and add an event filter in `MainWindow.cpp` (don't forget to declare in .h as well):

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event) {
  if (event->type() == QEvent::ApplicationDeactivate)
    popup_spec->base->hide();
  return QWidget::eventFilter(object, event);
}
```

This will hide the helper widget when switching apps. If you want the reverse functionality to show the helper widget when application gets activated, In the same event filter check for `QEvent::ApplicationActivate` and call `popup_spec->base->show();`

Comment: I was trying to implement this behavior when I stumbled upon this question. Your solution does work but there is a catch. Suppose that `popup_spec` is invisible when the application was deactivated. It will be visible when the app is activated again, right? So the only way I found to fix this is to store the state of my application dialogs when I receive the `ApplicationDeactivate` event.